# When to use either the word "by" or "depending on" to classify something?

Tags: expression-choice

I was writing some English sentences and I found that the following sentences both seem good to me.

> The students are sorted by their scores.

> The students are sorted depending on their scores.

The only difference between them is the word "by" and "depending on".

I searched the examples of the word "sort" in the dictionary, and the dictionary says "after the word 'sort', 'by' usually follows it".
But doesn't it make sense to use "depending on" in place of "by" in this situation?

Thank you.

Comment: You might also say '...according to...'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a rough guide, in the Corpus of Contemporary American English there are 122 hits for the string 'BE SORT by' and zero for 'BE SORT depending on'. A similar comparison in the WEB corpus yields 6,522 hits for the former and 6 for the latter.

This would seem to indicate that the *by* version is by far the more common, though the *depending on* version does not strike me as unintelligible in the following example.

> All cork stoppers are visually sorted **depending on** their quality
> grade. ([WidgetCo](https://www.widgetco.com/28-cork-stoppers-extra))

It does however leave open the interpretation of *these stoppers are sorted if they meet the required quality grade* OR *these stoppers are sorted in different ways depending on their quality grade*.

The *by* choice avoids any ambiguity, and is the natural choice. That being said, it seems unlikely the *depending on* version would be misinterpreted or found jarring in context.